# Storing values in form of list, C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

I want to save the following value in C#

```
10.1.2.1  <name of branch like BRANCH-A> Status (up/down) Average_Latency
```

I dont want to use a database. Is there any native datastructure in C# to store this value, like list or dictionary ? i think dictionary can store only key value pair, over here, i have 1 key (the ip address) and 3 values.

How can i store it

EDIT Sorry Sir. I want to save it in memory, in disk it would be easy using csv files. I am sorry for confusion

Comment: do you want to store this in memory or make it persistent in disk?

Comment: please clarify what exactly you want to save and where you want to save it (disk, memory).. your question is imho much to vague

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `Tuple<string, bool, int>` if you're using .NET Framework 4, but that is really suboptimal, compared to creating a dedicated class.

Just create a class that holds each item.

```
public class NetworkStats {
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public bool IsUp { get; set; }
    public int AvgLatency { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a `Dictionary<string, NetworkStats>` for holding the data.

Comment: Sorry Sir but this is not what i want, i have total of 300 IPs i want to monitor, so i needed to store them in a dictionary style datastructure. How i can use class ? you mean i shall create 300 objects out of it ? kindly guide me

Comment: In my opinion, this answer is exactly what you need for solving your in-memory storing issues. What you need to do to get further help is to explain a bit more about your requirements and your environment. How is the data collected? Is there a GUI? And so on. And then perhaps learn some more programming, basic OOP and C#.

Comment: I am banned. I am sorry but can someone help me get my privilege back :-(. Sorry if i offended you atornblad.

Comment: No offence taken. I just don't think you understood my initial answer.